# Regarding Execution of jar file through command line

Tags: android

I downloaded both Jar files (AndroidScreencast.jar & ddmlib.jar) and the androidscreencast.jnlp, when I click the jnlp file while offline I cannot open screencast, how can I run this offline if I have the files already downloaded?

When i run it from command line.
I get the following message:

no main manifest attribute, in androidscreencast.jar